# Evaluate $ \int \frac{(\cos^3x)}{(\sin^2x)}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

How do you integrate the equation $$ \int \frac{(\cos^3x)}{(\sin^2x)}dx $$ using U substitution?

Comment: Write $\int \dfrac{1-\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}\cos x dx$ and let $\sin x=u$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \sin x$, then $du=\cos x dx$. One has $$\int \frac{1-u^2}{u^2}du = \int (\frac{1}{u^2}-1)du = -\frac{1}{u}-u.$$

Comment: $+C{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 0):

with the hint from above we get
$$\int\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}dt=\int\frac{1}{t^2}-1dt$$